# who first sets tcp FIN flag in client-server connection

Tags: tcp, client-server

Who should first set the TCP FIN flag.  Server, when finished sending data, or Client, when received complete data?

regards

Answer (score 15):

`FIN` is sent when the application on that side requests that the connection be closed.  This doesn't have to happen immediately after receiving a `FIN` from the other side, either - it's possible for one side to send a `FIN`, then the other side to send some more data before sending its own `FIN`.

Once the TCP connection is up, it's completely symmetrical - neither side is distinguishable as a "server" or "client".  This implies that either side can send the first `FIN`.  Since a host can send no more data on a connection after sending a `FIN`, it is usually the side that first knows that it has no more data to send that does so.

There is a good practical reason to design a network protocol so that the client is the one that first closes the connection - the "first closer" ends up in `TIME_WAIT` state for twice the Maximum Segment Lifetime, which is a few minutes.  This occupies a small amount of resources for those minutes - but if this happens on the server side where the server is handling many hundreds of connections a second, those `TIME_WAIT` sockets will quickly add up.  It's better to distribute this burden out among the clients.

Comment: More details on TIME_WAIT can be found here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html

Comment: @caf Please see http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/08/12/where-do-resets-come-from-no-the-stork-does-not-bring-them.aspx they say that both sides suffer from TIME_WAIT

Comment: @entropy: No, it doesn't.  Anyway, you can readily consult any reference containing the state diagram of TCP to see that it is the first closer that enters `TIME_WAIT`.  The second closer goes through `CLOSE_WAIT` and `LAST_ACK` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the application layer protocol. - from http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm.

> A TCP connection is normally
>   terminating using a special procedure
>   where each side independently closes
>   its end of the link. It normally
>   begins with one of the application
>   processes signalling to its TCP layer
>   that the session is no longer needed.
>   That device sends a FIN message to
>   tell the other device that it wants to
>   end the connection, which is
>   acknowledged. When the responding
>   device is ready, it too sends a FIN
>   that is acknowledged; after waiting a
>   period of time for the ACK to be
>   received, the session is closed.

In practice, it *should* usually be the client, but there is no reason why it must be so.